# Error installing CocoaPods

Tags: macos, open-source

I am trying to install CocoaPods on my Mac device. When I run the following command:

`sudo gem install cocoapods`

it returns:

```
Fetching: cocoapods-core-1.5.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed cocoapods-core-1.5.3

ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods: invalid gem: package metadata is missing in /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/cache/cocoapods-deintegrate-1.0.2.gem
```

What is casing this issue and how do I install CocoaPods?

Comment: What is your question? What have you already tried to solve the problem? Can you install other gems without problems?

Comment: Not installed so far - @ nohillside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install [CocoaPods](https://cocoapods.org).

If you are not already using Homebrew, it is a package manager for macOS, hugely popular among developers of all types. It makes installing packages like CocoaPods hassle free.

To install Homebrew, follow the instructions on the [homepage](https://brew.sh)

> Paste that at a Terminal prompt.
>
> ```
> /usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
> ```

Homebrew requires Xcode Command Line Tools to be installed and setup (which I am assuming you already have as you are trying to install CocoaPods, implying you are developing for iOS).

Once Homebrew is setup, simply run:

`brew install cocoapods`

to install CocoaPods.

Comment: I was using  sudo gem install cocoapods with sierra, got me errors... 
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/2.3.0/mkmf.rb:456:in `try_do': The compiler failed to generate an executable file. (RuntimeError)
You have to install development tools first.

went then to the logs and saying that  :package configuration for libffi is not found.
 
your solution worked for me. thanks !!